How to write an SLD to put the lower left corner of the external symbol on the points in GeoServer
I have a point layer in GeoServer and I used a simple SLD like this:
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>points</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>symbols from png</sld:Name>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Title>Display lower left corner of symbol on point</sld:Title>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:ExternalGraphic>
                <sld:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="file:///C:/GeoServer/Red_Symbols_VN301/symbol.png"/>
                <sld:Format>image/png</sld:Format>                
              </sld:ExternalGraphic>
            <sld:Size>90</sld:Size> 
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>



it put the center of my external PNGs on the points but I want to put the lower left corner of them on points.
How should I do it in an SLD of GeoServer?
I have already tried this:
<Displacement>
  <DisplacementX>
     10
  </DisplacementX>
  <DisplacementY>
      0
  </DisplacementY>
</Displacement>


It gave me errors that say child is not expected. I think it is because Displacement tag is only for labeling and not for the pointSymbolizer.

I think you can modify the SVG to move the origin, I'm not sure that GeoServer allows you to move symbol
